# C#: Select value from a column in dataset using 2nd column as criteria

Tags: c#, select, dataset

I have a dataset pulling from my database with 2 columns.
I need to select a value from the 2nd column in my database "Column B", based on the value in the same row of "Column A"

```
'Column A'  'Column B'
   1111       aaaa
   1212       bbbb
   1313       caca
    etc        etc
```

So in this example, I need to select the value in Column B by using the Column A value 1212 resulting in selecting bbbb which I can store in a string.  I will need to do this multiple times for the varying values in the table.

Here is what I am working with so far:

```
sSql.Remove(0, sSql.Length);
        sSql.Append("SELECT NAME_, VALUE_TEXT");
        sSql.Append(" FROM PARAMETERS_");
        sSql.Append(" WHERE PARAMETERS_.NAME_ = 'Captions.User_TxtBox1'");
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.DataSources.OleDBDataSource) rpt.DataSource).ConnectionString.ToString());
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand selectCmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sSql.ToString(), conn);
        da.SelectCommand = selectCmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

    txtUser.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["VALUE_TEXT"].ToString();
```

This works, but for one record only.  I want to be able to remove my WHERE clause in my SQL statement and select the specific records I am looking for from the entire table.  I am grabbing a series of entries where the values for PARAMETERS_.NAME_ will be equal to Captions.Tool1, Captions.Tool2, etc., and I will need to know what the VALUE_TEXT for those rows will be, so I can place those values in the corresponding text box.

Comment: A bit of code please?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "dataset". What object contains these rows?

Comment: Ammended with code currently in use.

Comment: What is the problem? You can load all records into dictionary and search by the key (column A). That is effectively "removing your Where clause". You can also have a dataset loaded and use "Select" on your dataset, which is more flexible.

Comment: +1 for dictionary. If you want to randomly find values by NAME_ then make NAME_ the key of a dictionary and VALUE_TEXT the value of the dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, I am very unfamiliar with dictionary and its uses.  I am a beginner with C# and have limited knowledge so far.  Unfortunately, the platform I have to code on for my report to run does not have intelisense either.  

I will begin to research dictionary.

Comment: Then, I guess, you need to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415.aspx). Filter rows by *Column A* value, select from *Column B* from filtered rows, and (optionally) take first result:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Column A") == 1212)
                  .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Column B"))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The problem there will be that it is not likely that my results will sort in the manner I would think they should.

I may have hundreds of values in column a that I dont know exist, but i DO know the value I am looking for exists.

Comment: @user2561510 if you want to sort result by some filed, use `.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("Column B"))`. If you will remove `FirstOrDefault()` then you will get all values in a `IEnumerable<string>` collection.

Comment: I dont think a sort is going to help me in this situation.  I have added some existing code I am using but trying to eliminate the WHERE clause in the SQL statement so I can pull multiple records, one for each text box I need to insert the string in.

Comment: @user2561510 sorry, I don't understand what is your problem now

Comment: The LINQ query solution should work regardless of how the data is sorted.